# Extension Formhandler: database insert

Tags: typo3

I've got a problem with inserting data to the database using extension formhandler.

This is my html for the form:

```
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_FORM1### begin -->
<form action="###REL_URL###" id="projektform" method="post" class="formhandler">
 <dl>
  <dt><label for="sender_name">Imię</label></dt>
  <dd>
   <input type="text" name="formhandler[sender_name]" id="sender_name"
          value="###value_sender_name###" />
  </dd>

  <dt><label for="sender_email">E-mail</label></dt>
  <dd>
   <input type="text" name="formhandler[sender_email]" id="sender_email"
          value="###value_sender_email###" />
  </dd>

  <dt><label for="message">Wiadomość</label></dt>
  <dd>
   <textarea name="formhandler[message]" id="message">###value_message###</textarea>
  </dd>
 </dl>
 <input type="submit" value="Wyślij" ###submit_nextStep### />
</form>
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_FORM1### end -->

<!-- ###TEMPLATE_SUBMITTEDOK### begin -->
<p>The following message has been sent:</p>
<p>###value_message###</p>
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_SUBMITTEDOK### end -->

<!-- ###TEMPLATE_EMAIL_ADMIN_PLAIN### begin -->
The following contact form has been sent to you:
Sender: ###value_sender_name### ###value_sender_email###
Text:
###value_message###
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_EMAIL_ADMIN_PLAIN### end -->
```

And this is my typoscript for the form:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {   
  debug = 1    
  templateFile = fileadmin/forms/contact-form/1-contactform.html  
  formValuesPrefix = formhandler    
  finishers {     
    1 {       
      class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail     
    }     
    2 {       
      class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_SubmittedOK       
      config.returns = 1     
    } 
    3.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_DB  
    3.config {
      table = contact  
      fields {
        sender_name.mapping = sender_name
        sender_email.mapping = sender_email
        message.mapping = message
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Mails submitted through the form are sent but still inserting into database is not working. 
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the table name is OK? A TYPO3 table needs to be prefixed with tx_ in order to be working.

Comment: You can don't have to use the prefix tx_ for the tables. It also works fine with a table name without the tx_ prefix (e.g tt_content, fe_users or a user defnied table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Finisher_SubmittedOK` should always be used as the last finisher, since it stops executing following finishers. The [documentation](http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/finisher/finisher-submittedok/) also shows, that this finisher should be used as the last one.

Change you TypoScript as following and the form values will be saved to your table.

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings {   
  debug = 1    
  templateFile = fileadmin/1-contactform.html  
  formValuesPrefix = formhandler    
  finishers {     
    1 {       
      class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_Mail     
    }     
    2.class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_DB  
    2.config {
      table = contact  
      fields {
        sender_name.mapping = sender_name
      }
    }
    3 {       
      class = Tx_Formhandler_Finisher_SubmittedOK       
      config.returns = 1     
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: It looks like I simply missed that part with Finisher_SubmittedOK it works now. Thanks a lot for Your help :)